# null reference exception while trying to post to facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, nullreferenceexception

I have text on one webpage that I am trying to feed to a facebook post. I know the facebook posting code is correct because if I replace my facebookMsg String with hardcoded text it posts just fine. The issue I am running into is somehow I am loosing the text from the previous page. I have included at the top of my facebookPost.aspx page: <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %> which tells me I should be able to access the Default pages controls I have tried Server.Transfer("~/FacebookPost.aspx", true); as well as Response.Redirect("~/FacebookPost.aspx"); and both give me the same error.

Here is my code:

**Image Button click event from Default.aspx:**

```
protected void FacebookImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int fb = 1;

        HiddenField1.Value += "*facebook=" + fb.ToString(); ;
        //Server.Transfer("~/FacebookPost.aspx", true);
        Response.Redirect("~/FacebookPost.aspx");
    }
```

**Here is the snippet of code where the exception is being thrown:**

```
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf('=') + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                 setFacebookMessage(PreviousPage.SocialMediaPost);


                //need to install facebook SDK for .net: 
                //tools/library package manager/manage nuget packages for solution search online for Facebook and install
                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = facebookMsg });
                //Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Response.Write(e.ToString() + "<br/><br/>" + url);
            }
```

**Here is the setFacebookMessage Method in my facebookPost.aspx.cs:**

```
    protected void setFacebookMessage(String tempString)
    {            
               facebookMsg = tempString;       
    }
```

**Finally, my SocialMediaPost in my Default.aspx.cs:**

```
 public String SocialMediaPost
    {
        get
        {
            return SocialMediaHiddenField.Value;
        }
    }
```

When I debug I can't even get the system to switch over to the Default.aspx.cs code to go get the HiddenField values so it's as if it is loosing that page altogether.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Perhaps using the [cross page postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx) capabilities of .net will help?

Comment: I have referenced those instructions and have input the proper code with the  <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %> on the target page and the public property: public String SocialMediaPost in the Source. Which is why I am not understanding why it is not finding the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. There was a Response.Redirect occurring which was causing the page to load as a brand new page vs. a postback therefore the values were being passed in but once the redirect occurred they were being lost and the Previous Page was now something new.

To solve the issue I used Session. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This allowed me to place the passed value into Session where it could be held through the redirect and accessed after it.